# Storm logviewer page not found

Tags: apache-storm, log-viewer

I'm able to submit a topology job in the multi-tenant cluster. The job is running. However, the logviewer page is not available. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: do you mean to say you are not able to see the logs from the storm ui? kindly put some more details whats exactly you are doing.

Comment: I see in Storm UI that logviewer.port=8000, but when I access that port on the target machine only a page with "Page not found" will be displayed

Comment: For us, it was an issue with public & private IP addresses. When you get to the "page not found" URL, try changing the host to the public IP or public host name.

Answer (score 21):

you need to start the logviewer before you click on `topology port` to see logviewer.
To start logviewer run:
`$ storm logviewer` same as you run `$ storm list`

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same issue for logviewer's home page, but directly navigating to a particular log file that exists in the logs folder works. Try this:

MachineIP:8000/log?file=worker-6700.log