# History of Storm topologies

Tags: apache-storm

Is there a way to find out how many topologies have ever been deployed on a Storm cluster? What if there is only one node or local deployment? I want to know the entire history of any topologies ever deployed. Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: I am not aware of such a feature.

Comment: thanks, also how can i view the logs on storm ui ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538327/storm-logviewer-page-not-found